# Using html-agility-pack in Linqpad results in compile time error

Tags: html-agility-pack, linqpad

When I try use HTMLAgilityPack in LinqPad as follows:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
```

Full file at: http://share.linqpad.net/9ri8xq.linq

I get the error:

```
CS0433 The type 'HtmlDocument' exists in both 
'HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore, Version=1.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
and
'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a'
```

I'm not clear how to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

You included the NuGet package [Html2Markdown](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Html2Markdown/) into the Linqpad query. But that's a .Net-core package which is dependent of HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore. This dependency is downloaded and included as well, but of course that doesn't mix with the HTMLAgilityPack package written for .Net-"tradional".

You're going to have to choose which package you want to use.